# Entity beans alternatives

Tags: hibernate, entity, ejb-2.x

I'm migrating a legacy application that uses EJB 2.x Entity beans from JBoss5.x to Wildfly. Having understood that Entity beans are no longer supported in Wildfly, I'm looking for alternate solutions. We can **not** take Hibernate an option because we use a proprietary database that doesn't have a proper dialect. However I'm interested in Hibernate like features such as auto persistence of dirty objects (which were maintained earlier with EJB 2.x lifecycle methods), possibly with caching & JTA support.

Please suggest if there any other solutions available meeting these requirements, other than Hibernate?

Comment: May be look into the below urls and get the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665036/alternatives-to-hibernate

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-hibernate-alternatives